# How to add subprojects to iOSOpenDev?

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, theos, cydia

I have been making jailbreak tweak recently and have just been using a normal text editor for everything and then compiling and installing using a makefile(THEOS). I have tried using iOSOpenDev before but didn't like it because in my projects I normally have multiple subprojects. For example, I have my main tweak project, then I also have a preference bundle and another tweak as subprojects of the main tweak. When I use NIC.pl to create a new project inside of another it just adds the lines:

```
SUBPROJECTS += MY_SUBPROJECT_NAME_HERE
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/aggregate.mk
```

to the makefile of the main project and then the subprojects get compiled and installed with the main one. I have never been able to use iOSOpenDev because I was never able to figure out how to get this functionality with using iOSOpenDev. How can I have multiple subprojects using iOSOpenDev?

Thanks!